# Assign model variable in a strongly typed view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model-binding

I have a `ModelA` model and a strongly typed view `ViewA` which is typed to `ModelA`. As you know if you declare an action say 'ActionAPost' with a signature like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ActionAPost(ModelA mod) {
  // code
}
```

It will bind the values setted on the form to ModelA instance in this case `mod`. I want to do something like this:

ViewA:

```
@ModelAInstance.SomeAttr = ViewBag.SomeAttr;
```

Assign some value staticaly to the model attribute that will be processed by the post action.

Edit:

The value is set on `ViewBang` previously.

Comment: I've tried that, but as far as i know to get access to @Model you have to pass it from the action View(ModelA). It's just that you end up with two diferent instances and just one accesible from the post action, the one you receive on the parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So in the view have a hidden element where the name attribute reflects the object path of the model and property. This way it will bind back to your POST action how you want it

Example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="SomeAttr" value="@ViewBag.SomeAttr" />
```

With Razor and the `ViewBag` value

Set the value in the Model in your `GET` request then with razor:

```
@Html.Hidden("SomeAttr", (object)ViewBag.SomeAttr);
```

<s>`@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SomeAttr, new { value = ViewBag.SomeAttr });`</s>

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the assignment bust be done from a razor statement, see my edit.

Comment: The second way worked, why it didn't ocurred to me the hidden input, tnx.

Answer (score 1):

Create a hidden variable in your form, with the **same name** as the property name of your ViewModel

```
<input type="hidden" name="SomeAttr" value="@ViewBag.SomeAttr" />
```

Now in your post action, you can get this by accessing the SomeAttr property

```
public ActionResult Add(ModelA model)
{
  //check for model.SomeAttr here

}
```

Assuming your Model ,`ModelA` has a `SomeAttr` property. MVC Modelbinding will bind your input to the model object when it gets posted.